# IE 11, Edge - when a file upload button is pressed, it auto submit the form instead of wait

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, file-upload, multipartform-data

Without hitting submit when i click file browser button it already submit the form? How to prevent it in IE 11/IE Edge (all other browsers can handle it).

CSS:

```
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Html:

```
<form method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form1" name="form1">

   <div class="upload-btn-wrapper">

    <button class="btn">upload file</button>
       <input type="file" class="form-control" 
               placeholder="" id='files' name='files' onchange="files(this);"/>

   </div>
```

JS:

```
function files(elm) {
  var fn = $(elm).val();
  var filename = fn.match(/[^\\/]*$/)[0];
  //$('#selected_filename').html(filename);
}
```

Comment: You could use event.preventDefault(); to stop submitting form.

Comment: Where to put that ?